# Xcode Error compiling not working with fvm default as sdk path

Tags: flutter, dart, xcode14, fvm

» fvm flutter run
No devices found yet. Checking for wireless devices...
Launching lib/main.dart on Ninja1(`physical iOS test device`) in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: #######
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           28.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

```
Error (Xcode): ../../../fvm/versions/3.10.5/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/matchers.dart:898:62: Error: The parameter 'matchState' of the method '_FindsWidgetMatcher.matches' has type 'Map<String, dynamic>', which does not match the corresponding type, 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>', in the overridden method, 'Matcher.matches'.
```

» flutter run                               1 ↵
No devices found yet. Checking for wireless devices...
Launching lib/main.dart on Ninja1 in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode
project: #######
Running pod install...                                             20.4s
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           158.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

```
Error (Xcode): ../../../fvm/versions/3.10.5/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/matchers.dart:898:62:
Error: The parameter 'matchState' of the method '_FindsWidgetMatcher.matches' has type
'Map<String, dynamic>', which does not match the corresponding type, 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>',
in the overridden method, 'Matcher.matches'.
```

Started out running

`fvm global 3.10.5`

making flutter 3.10.5

then running `flutter run`

that Failed... so I ran
`fvm use 3.10.5`
`fvm flutter run`
also failed

both `flutter run` && `fvm flutter run` && running from `Xcode`
reeached the same error highligthed above

`pubspec.yaml`

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=3.0.5 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  auto_route: ^7.7.1
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  dartz: ^0.10.1
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+2
  easy_localization: ^3.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.2.0
  firebase_core: ^2.4.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.7
  firebase_messaging: ^14.1.4
  flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
  flutter_form_builder: ^9.1.0
  flutter_gen: ^5.0.1
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.5.3+2
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.7
  form_builder_extra_fields: ^10.0.0
  form_builder_validators: ^9.0.0
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  google_fonts: ^5.1.0
  http: ^1.1.0
  image_cropper: ^5.0.0
  image_picker: ^1.0.1
  injectable: ^2.1.0
  internet_connection_checker: ^1.0.0+1
  intl: ^0.18.0
  json_annotation: ^4.8.1
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.2
  pinput: ^2.2.11
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  flutter_dash: ^1.0.0
  crypto: ^3.0.2
  flutter_local_notifications: ^15.1.0+1
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.6
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  dots_indicator: ^3.0.0
  package_info_plus: ^4.0.2
  url_launcher: ^6.1.11
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.3.0
  external_app_launcher: ^3.1.0
  flutter_jailbreak_detection: ^1.10.0
  # flutter_test:
  #   sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  auto_route_generator: ^7.2.0
  build_runner: ^2.2.1
  flutter_gen_runner: ^5.0.1
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1
  injectable_generator: ^2.1.3
  json_serializable: ^6.2.0
```

same result with `flutter_test` packaged when enabled or disabled